# How I can make unique and following id in xsd schema?

Tags: xsd

I don't know if XSD permits that but i'd like make my unique id (I already know how to make them) to be a sequence of number.

example :

```
<object id="0" />
<object id="2" />
<object id="1" />
```

would be correct but

```
<object id="0" />
<object id="2" />
<object id="3" />
```

would be not.

the ids must start from 0 and all number must be here (no missing number) (but with a quantity of "object" not fixed.

I don't know if this is really clear. Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't your firts example be: 0, 1, 2? If not explain the difference...

Comment: @rene: I gather order/sorting doesn't matter, the only thing that matters is that they are an unbroken sequence starting from 0.

Comment: @rene: this is exactly what Wrikken said